# How to filter data by an async method in EFCore?

Tags: c#, .net-core, ef-core-3.1

I want to filter my data by ef core and I'm trying to filter users by an async method that returns `Task<bool>`.

```
var query = _context.User.AsQueryable();
query.Where(async (arg) => await _userInterface.CheckUserAvabilityAsync(user, arg.Id) == true);
```

But with this code, I get this error

CS4010: Cannot convert async lambda expression to delegate type 'Func<User, bool>'. An async lambda expression may return void, Task or Task, none of which are convertible to 'Func<User, bool>'.

So how can i filter my asqueryable data by my method?

Comment: That would be meaningless.  EF Core is an ORM. It translates LINQ queries to SQL. What you posted couldn't be translated to SQL even if it was a simple function call - how is a call to a local method going to be translated to SQL. As for async, SQL queries don't specify how data is retrieve, they specify what the data should be. Asynchronous execution has no meaning in a SQL query

Answer (score 1):

That error is telling you that you can't use async inside your predicate.

You need to change your approach, unfortunately, looping through in-memory data.

```
// Get all data, convert to list
List<User> userRecords = _context.User.ToList();
List<User> availableUsers = new List<User>();
foreach (User userRecord in userRecords)
{
    //Assuming you will always successfully receive a boolean
    if (await _userInterface.CheckUserAvabilityAsync(user, userRecord.Id))
        availableUsers.push(userRecord);
}
return availableUsers;
```

That should do the trick.